# Bootstrap Responsive Grid Getting One Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing a website using bootstrap 3. In the part of Image Gallery, I made a Grid Layout using .row class and 4 columns per row, like the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-2">
        <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-2">
       <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-2">
        <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
     </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-2">
            <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

When I do a cross-browser test, in the small[lower] resolutions I get a one column layout. But I want it to appear in two-columns in small[lower] resolutions.

The unique solution that I found in-order to get a two-column layout in small[lower] resolutions is using, .visible class from bootstrap like the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-2">
            <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-2">
            <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-2">
            <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-2">
            <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

But, it causes my website to load the content twice, and it is not good for performance.

Some one here can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: a jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com or bootply.com playground would be fine to play.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you should use `.col-sm-6`

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class=".col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-xs-2">
     <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
   </div>
   <div class=".col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-xs-2">
     <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
   </div>
   <div class=".col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-xs-2">
     <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
   </div>
   <div class=".col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-xs-2">
     <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want 4 columns per row on large resolutions and 2 columns per row on small resolutions. To do this, try something like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <p>Your Content goes Here!</p>
    </div>
  </div>       
</div>
```

All you need to do is change your `col-xs-2` to `col-xs-6`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/hJyY4/

Answer (score 0):

replace `col-xs-2` with `col-xs-6` and it should work as `col-xs-6` will give it 50% width and hence 2 columns on a row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```